# Define cron for mongodb table removing

Tags: scripting, mongodb, cron

I want to run `db.clickreferrerurls.remove()` command for mongodb from crontab by defining cron job at local machine.

How I could do this?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `--eval` argument to `mongo`. e.g.

```
/usr/bin/mongo --eval "db.clickreferrerurls.remove()"
```

Comment: or if you prefer you can put that line in a .js file and run "mongo <scriptname>

Comment: is it not necesseray to specify the database ?